# Is the occurrence of a particular enzyme in a given subcellular location a random phenomenon?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes

Enzymes occur in different subcellular locations. Some are specific to a given subcellular location, whereas others are heterogeneously distributed. What evolutionary decisions influence the occurence of enzymes in particular compartments?. Are the locations species-specific?

Comment: Some trace their evolutionary origin in the ancestral organelles (such as mitochondria and plastids) and therefore they are localized in those organelles. Can you add more details to make your question more specific?

Comment: I have edited the question above. I wanted to know more about this. Thanks

Comment: You have changed your question completely. What's more it is now nonsense: "What evolutionary decisions..." Evolutionary decisions indeed! And If you have to ask about enzyme locations being species-specific I suggest you ask yourself why enzymes are in particular organelles and whether organelles are species-specific. Do some reading about organelles yourself, instead of wasting our time.

Comment: Dear David, First of all, you edited my question. I just re-phrased it.This was the same question I was asking from the beginning. I respect your comment. If you don't understand the question, you cannot comment on the question being non-sense. As you know more than me or anyone in this group, I'm just asking you the same question "Why do enzymes occur in specific locations? And What evolutionary decisions influence the occurrence of enzymes in particular compartments?" This may sound a very general question. I just want examples. A review article that explains this question might be useful.

Comment: Also, there have been many proteomics studies in related species of bacteria, parasites, etc. where the same enzymes can be found in different subcellular location. I'm just adding to their observation my question as to why they might occur in different locations and also why they are species-specific. If I could not clarify my message still, then its worthy to close this question totally. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are various methods for targetting proteins to subcellular organelles or membrane locations. In general they depend on ‘tagging’ or ‘signal’ sequences in the proteins. Such tags or signals are recognized by specialized proteins that are able to conduct the protein through the membrane barrier to the particular location.

The individual processes for different target locations vary, so I do not think it appropriate to provide details here. You can read a summary of them in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_targeting). For more extensive treatment you can look at the relevant chapters in [Lodish *et al.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21475/?term=protein%20targeting)  or in [Alberts *et al.*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21054/?term=protein%20targeting) on-line (old edition).

(Please consider donating to Wikipedia, if you use it.)

Comment: It might be too broad a topic to be explained here, but you should at least describe some part of it (even if introductory) lest this is too short to be an answer.

Comment: @HomoSapien — It may be better to close it as too broad. I looked to see if it were answered previously. I'll add another sentence, but more than that...

Comment: Yeah, but that is another point. I meant that just giving some references would be appropriate for a question, especially if its too broad.

Comment: @HomoSapien — I think the two book refs are ok. They give a breakdown of the chapters for different locations (nucleus, peroxisome, membrane etc.) That seems to me a good entry point for a novice.

Comment: Yeah, they are. +1 for you mentioned donating for wikipedia ;)

Comment: Enzymes occur in different subcellular locations. Some are specific to a subcellular location. Some are heterogeneously distributed. Lets take the example of metabolic enzymes. The location of an enzyme in a particular subcellular location may dictate the flow of metabolites through different compartments. I wanted to ask "what evolutionary decisions influence the occurence of enzymes in particular compartments?. Are the locations species-specific?". A review article, book or research article that explains this question might be useful. I'm editing the questions too.